# XCode does not let me change the code

Tags: xcode4

I have been working on a project and since last week xcode does not let me make any changes in my xib file and another page in the project. However I can make changes in other pages. When I open it as root I can make changes in main.xib as well. What can cause this? It is very annoying.

This is what I get:

“MainWindow.xib” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?

Comment: When I hit unlock it says I am not the owner of the file

Comment: Did you transfer this project from another account on the current computer, or from another computer all together?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have lost ownership of your own files (or some reason).  You can confirm this from the command line by simply listing them (`ls`), for example:

```
$ ls -l
total 184
-rwxr-xr-x  1 andy  staff   2731  7 Dec  2010 AppDelegate.h
-rwxr-xr-x  1 andy  staff   3976  7 Dec  2010 AppDelegate.m
-rwxr-xr-x  1 andy  staff   2625  7 Dec  2010 Choices.h
...
```

My username is 'andy', so I already own these files, however if I didn't, I could change ownership of the whole directory hierarchy using `chown` as root:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  12 andy  staff  408 15 Dec  2010 CFLocalServer
drwxr-xr-x  23 andy  staff  782 18 Dec  2010 GridMenu
drwxr-xr-x  12 andy  staff  408 16 Dec  2010 Hello
drwxr-xr-x  16 andy  staff  544 18 Dec  2010 NSTableViewBinding
drwxr-xr-x  18 andy  staff  612 18 Dec  2010 OpenCL_OceanWave
$ sudo chown -R andy:staff *
Password:
$
```

You can do this using Finder, but that isn't so easy to explain.

Ultimately you need to find out *why* you lost ownership as currently you are not in control of your own machine, it is in control of you.

Comment: +1 for probable solution, and for the last line, gave me a laugh.